# Incorrect sum of when averaging multiple numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf

I am attempting to create and array of the averages of elements from multiple numpy arrays. When adding two arrays together (either using `numpy.add()` or via broadcasting `a1 + a2`) the sums generated do not appear to be correct.

**Code**

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy
import os

data_dir = /my_data/
data_files = np.asarray(os.listdir(data_dir))
dataset = Dataset(os.path.join(data_dir,data_files[0]),'r')
vals_sum = np.zeros_like(dataset.variables["vals"][:][:])

for data_file in data_files:
    current_file = os.path.join(data_dir,data_file)
    dataset = Dataset(current_file,'r')
    vals = dataset.variables["vals"][:][:]

    print '1: sum', np.sum(vals)
    print '1: total sum', np.sum(vals_sum)

    vals_sum = np.add(vals, vals_sum)

    print '2: sum', np.sum(vals)
    print '2: total sum', np.sum(vals_sum)
    print '\n'
```

**Output** (with two data files in directory)

```
1: sum 29231.2
1: total sum 0.0
2: sum 29231.2
2: total sum 8249.65

1: sum 25840.5
1: total sum 8249.65
2: sum 25840.5
2: total sum 7055.33
```

I would expect that for the first file, the sum of the first array and the running sum should be the same. There are no negative values in either dataset, so how could this be?

**Update 1:**
After trying `vals = np.copy(dataset.variables["vals"])`, it appears to have transfered the missing values as `-999`, which did not occur with the other method for initialzing the array. It is still yielding incorrect sums, though:

```
1: sum -9.24455e+08
1: total sum 0.0
2: sum -9.24455e+08
2: total sum -8.10467e+07

1: sum -9.31734e+08
1: total sum -8.10467e+07
2: sum -9.31734e+08
2: total sum -1.57788e+08
```

**Update 2:**
Soooo... it appears that `netCDF4` auto-magically creates a masked numpy array when there are missing values in a netCDF dataset. When performing a `np.zeros_like()`, masked values are copied over. This means the zero-array I am creating from my first data file, despite it having the same number of elements, gets created with a mask where that file is missing data. When masked arrays are added together, so are their masks, which will give a different sum.

```
import numpy.ma as ma
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,5,7,-999,45,2,-999])
y = np.array([-999,89,-999,80,34,31,1])
mx = ma.masked_less(x,0)
my = ma.masked_less(y,0)
x0 = np.zeros_like(mx)
np.sum(my) # yields 235
np.sum(my+x0) # yields 154
```

The question is now,

### how do you create a cumulative mask for the given file/date range efficiently without processing initializing all of the data twice?

Comment: Why are you happy with the output of the first file?  Shouldn't `np.sum(vals)` and `np.sum(vals + vals_sum)` be the same thing for the first file?  But they are not.

Comment: Also, does `Dataset` open a file?  Do you need to close it first to make sure something weird isn't happening with them?  Try something like `with Dataset(current_file, 'r') as dataset:`

Comment: if `a1 + a2` is causing broadcasting so will `np.add(a1, a2)`.

Comment: @askewchan I'm not happy with the first output. I've updated the text of my question to reflect that. I have now also tried things with closing the file using `dataset.close()`, which didn't seem to help. @Bi Rico I would like to add the arrays element-wise, then divide by the number of arrays added to get the simple average, so `a1 + a2` or np.add(a1, a2) should work for me.

Comment: I suggest that for each file you print `vals.shape` and `vals_sum.shape`, to make sure no broadcasting is happening.  IF there is broadcasting, then each value in one or the other array will be counted several times (as many times as it had to be multiplied for the shapes to match).  For arrays, `a = [1,2,3]; b = [1]`, then `sum(a) + sum(b)` is not the same as `sum(a+b)` because `b` gets counted three times in the latter case.

Comment: What happens if you replace `vals = dataset.variables["vals"][:][:]` with `vals = np.copy(dataset.variables["vals"])`?

Comment: @askewchan the dimensions are all the same, so everything checks out there. Good to know how the broadcasting works, though! @Bi Rico Crazy! That copied over all the missing values as `-999`, but the sums are still incorrect. I'll add this to my question.

Comment: Not that it is related to the problem, but you could replace `vals_sum = np.add(vals, vals_sum)` by the more compact `vals_sum += vals`.